# how can i access some javaScript file from java in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have helloJava.HTML in my GWT project , within that html file , i have this javascript code

```
                        <script type="text/javascript">
function testJavaScript(var input){
    var var1inJS = "Default value";

    alert("Value of Var1 = " + var1inJS);
    var1inJS = input;
    alert("Value of Var1 = " + var1inJS);

    var var2inJS = "Waht is the value of Var2";

    alert("Value of Var2 = " + var2inJS);

}
```

now i want to call this method from my onmoduleLoad class(i.e from my java class).

is it possible ?

hellojava.html file

```
                            <!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the     -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into                -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration   -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype is not supported. -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <!--                                                               -->
    <!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
    <!--                                                               -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="HelloJSNI.css">

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- Any title is fine                         -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
    <!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
    <!-- be added before this line.                -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="hellojsni/hellojsni.nocache.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function testJavascript(var input){
        window.jsniAlert();
        var var1inJS = "Default value";

        alert("Value of Var1 = " + var1inJS);
        var1inJS = input;
        alert("Value of Var1 = " + var1inJS);

        var var2inJS = "Waht is the value of Var2";

        alert("Value of Var2 = " + var2inJS);

    }

    function callJava(){

    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <!--                                           -->
  <!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      -->
  <!-- you can leave the body empty if you want  -->
  <!-- to create a completely dynamic UI.        -->
  <!--                                           -->
  <body>

    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>

    <h1>JSNI EXAMPLE</h1>

    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;"></td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="nameFieldContainer"></td>
        <td id="sendButtonContainer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="color:red;" id="errorLabelContainer"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function syntax from Travis is correct, the problem is the name of the calling function and JS script is not *right*.

Here are the corrections

1. Error in the function declaration, you should not use `var` for
   the argument.
2. Remove the first row `window.jsniAlert();`
3. Correct the declaration of the second function `function
   callJava(){` to `function callJava(){`

Here is the code (lets call the function in JS `testJSnative`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testJSnative(input){
    //window.jsniAlert();
    var var1inJS = "Default value";

    alert("Value of Var1 = " + var1inJS);
    var1inJS = input;
    alert("Value of Var1 = " + var1inJS);

    var var2inJS = "What is the value of Var2";

    alert("Value of Var2 = " + var2inJS);

}

function callJava(){

}
</script>
```

Example of class implementing `EntryPoint`:

```
  public void onModuleLoad() {

    Button jsniButton = new Button("call JS");
    jsniButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        callJavascript();
      }
    });
    RootPanel.get().add(jsniButton);
  } 

  public native void callJavascript() /*-{
    $wnd.testJSnative("hello");
  }-*/;
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: thank you , my other method callJava () , i want to call a java class from this method , any sugestion for this

Comment: @user1226162 You're welcome. Find out more about GWT JSNI here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is approximately what you want:

```
public static native void callJavascript() /*-{
    $wnd.testJavaScript("hello");
}-*/;
```

and then call this method in your Java code: `callJavascript();`

Read Google's docs on JSNI:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI

Comment: try your way , its giving me this exception : javascriptexception:object doesnt support property or method 'testjavascript'

Comment: i was wondering , how does it know that my testjavascript is in helloJava.html

Comment: Is helloJava.html the page from which you're launching your GWT app? If not, it needs to be. Or you need to put this code in a separate `.js` file which you include in your main html page.

Comment: yes it is, i have also updated my question with .html file , in case i am doing some thing wrong there , thanks

Comment: It looks fine. I can't see everything you're doing so I don't know. Read the JSNI docs and learn about how it works, then you'll be able to debug it yourself.