# GWT:not able to call a javascript method which is in mymain.html class from my onmoduleload

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I am trying to call my Javascript method from my java in GWT
below is what i am doing

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    jsniAlert("test");
}

private static final native void jsniAlert(String test) /*-{
    $wnd.alert(test);
    $wnd.testJavascript();
}-*/;
```

HelloJSNI.html  (the main html class which use to open my application in war folder)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"  
    src="hellojsni/hellojsni.nocache.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function testJavascript(var input) {
        window.jsniAlert();
        var var1inJS = "Default value";

        alert("Value of Var1 = " + var1inJS);
        var1inJS = input;
        alert("Value of Var1 = " + var1inJS);

        var var2inJS = "Waht is the value of Var2";

        alert("Value of Var2 = " + var2inJS);   
    }
```

but when i run my application there's an exception

```
javascriptexception:object doesn't support property or method 'testjavascript'
```

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050909/how-can-i-access-some-javascript-file-from-java-in-gwt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your `testJavascript` function, so it is not getting loaded, and you can't call it.

Change this:

```
function testJavascript(var input) {
```

to this

```
function testJavascript(input) {  //notice that var keyword is not used to define parameters
```

Comment: changed it from var input to  input , but getting same error, any suggestion , thanks

Comment: You are most likely getting a different error `
Object [object DOMWindow] has no method jsniAlert`. And it is normal because there is no javascript function jsniAlert in your code, and you are calling it from `testJavascript` function

Answer (score 0):

your javascript function is not loaded.
in the browsers, when a browser detacts an error in the code between script tags, the code inside will not be loaded and it could lead into unexpected results.

Comment: Man you have a big trouble here: you are calling a function B from a function A, then this function B calls back the function A, which will be a dead loop of calling functions! remove window.jsniAlert();
from your testJavascript

Comment: thanks , removed jsniAlert , in fact i remove everything from the method,it will do nothing but it shouldn't give me any exception atleast.